# Regex (node js) works on linux but not on window 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I get the object `message` via http protocol.
This object has the `body` property.

```
message.body: 'Denversaurus $24.90' +
    'Bread with sesame, artisan meat, cheddar, Jurassic sauce, mustard and honey, lettuce, tomato and pickles.'
```

I apply the following regex to that variable:

```
const regex = new RegExp(/([\w\dà-ú'" ]+)R\$ ([\d+,\.]+)[\n\r]([ \w\dà-ú'"\.,\+\*\(\)]+)/)
const arrayMatch = regex.exec(message.body)
```

On linux, I get the expected result, but on windows, the `arrayMatch` variable returns with the value `null`. And I can't solve it.
Does anyone have the solution?

Comment: I get `null` on both Linux and Windows

Comment: If that regex really works, 1) your string is not what you shared and 2) the most probably fix is ``/([\wà-ú'" ]+)R\$ ([\d+,.]+)[\n\r]+([ \wà-ú'".,+*()]+)/``

Answer (score 0):

your regex is incorrect . please test all patterns first with online tools like :
https://debuggex.com

As for this, I have to make it clear to you that all APIs implemented by Node Js are multiplatform unless the command is specific to a particular operating system. But in the case of regex, it is supported by all operating systems.

Also, when you want to build a regex with a constructor, its argument must be a string.

```
let regex1 = /(\w+)/gi;
//or
let regex2 = new RegExp("(\\w+)", "gi")
```

Comment: (Noting that ES5+ the ctor can take a regex, ES6 adds taking flags to the regex ctor form. I *wouldn't*, but it's allowed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp)

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks✌

Comment: You have to double escape the backslash like this in the RegExp constructor or else the pattern will be the same as `/w+/gi` matching 1 or more `w` chars.

Comment: @Thefourthbird ok thanks✌

Answer (score 0):

They must only differ in line ends: `"\n"` is Linux-style and `"\r\n"` is Windows-style.

Use

```js
const regex = new RegExp(/([\wà-ú'" ]+)R\$ ([\d+,\.]+)[\n\r]+([ \wà-ú'"\.,\+\*\(\)]+)/)
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\wà-ú'" ]+              any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), 'à' to 'ú', ''', '"', ' '
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  R                        'R'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \$                       '$'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\d+,\.]+                any character of: digits (0-9), '+',
                             ',', '\.' (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\n\r]+                  any character of: '\n' (newline), '\r'
                           (carriage return) (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ \wà-                    any character of: ' ', word characters
    ú'"\.,\+\*\(\)]+         (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _), 'à' to 'ú', ''',
                             '"', '\.', ',', '\+', '\*', '\(', '\)'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
```